# Auth0 asks for consent to access tenent when logging in

Tags: auth0

I am developing an Angular2 app which uses auth0 for authentication. I used the auth0 lock widget to authenticate users.

Now, I want to use `auth0-js` instead of the lock widget for authentication. I followed [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login) guide to add `auth0-js` to the app.

After adding `auth-js`, when a new user tries to log in to the app, Auth0 displays following consent screen to the user.

[image]

I want the users to be able to directly access my app, without needing to accept a consent screen. The consent question asked in this dialog can be confusing to users since it mentions about tenants.

When I searched for a solution, the solution mentioned in various places was to make the client a `first party` client. But, I cannot find any place in the management console to make the client a `first party` client.

How can I disable this consent screen?

Following is the `auth-js` config I used in the app.

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: 'my_client_id',
    domain: 'my_domain.auth0.com',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'https://my_domain.auth0.com/userinfo',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/auth_loading',
    scope: 'openid'
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **Auth0 Dashboard**, under `APIs -> Auth0 Management API -> Settings (tab)`

[image]

If you are using a specific `audience` for a Resource API you have defined yourself in the Dashboard, then there is a similar `Allow Skipping User Consent` toggle for that particuar API. Use that. `audience` specifies the target API for your access token. If you don't want to call a specific API, keep it set to https://my_domain.auth0.com/userinfo

Re. question about `First Party`. If you created your client in the Auth0 Dashboard, then it is `Firsty Party` by default. Only first-party clients can skip the consent dialog, assuming the resource server they are trying to access on behalf of the user has the "Allow Skipping User Consent" option enabled. The Auth0 Dashboard does not offer a flag for this, but if you use the Auth0 Management API v2 `Get Clients` endpoint, then you will see the flag (boolean) value listed for your client eg.

```
"is_first_party": true
```

See https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Clients/get_clients for details.

Finally, please note the following: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/user-consent#skipping-consent-for-first-party-clients - in particular note that consent cannot be skipped on localhost. As per the docs (link above), During development, you can work around this by modifying your /etc/hosts file (which is supported on Windows as well as Unix-based OS's) to add an entry such as the following:

```
127.0.0.1       myapp.dev
```

Comment: I have `Allow Skipping User Consent` enabled in the Auth0 Management API. I do not have any other API defined. Still the consent page comes up. Also, I observed that if I remove `audience` property in `auth0.WebAuth` constructor, consent is not asked. What is the purpose of this `audience` parameter? Is it OK if I kept it removed?

Comment: @LahiruChandima This can also happen if you're running in `localhost`. You might want to edit your `/etc/hosts` file to map localhost to a domain as shown here: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/user-consent#skipping-consent-for-first-party-clients

`audience` specifies the target API for your access token. If you don't want to call a specific API, keep it set to `https://my_domain.auth0.com/userinfo`

Comment: thanks @thameera - have added the clarifications into answer.

Comment: @LahiruChandima - hi, does the answer (with edits) now give you all the information you needed?

Comment: @arcseldon I think the problem should have been the fact that I was testing with `localhost`, as mentioned by thameera. But, I am unable to verify this now because I removed `auth-js` implementation and decided to stick with lock widget.

Comment: Thanks. If you could mark the answer correct (it includes all necessary info) that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I have Allow Skipping User Consent enabled in the Auth0 Management API. But when I login with username and password, it show the error "WE'RE SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHEN ATTEMPTING TO LOG IN.". In the Console tab of Chrome, there's nothing, but in the Network tab there's an authenticate request with status 200. Any Ideas?